# Getting weather data for multiple stations conditional for specific dates in R

Tags: r, package, weatherdata

I have the following problem:

For an analysis of weather effects on volunteers observing nature (animals, plants etc.) for a  citizen science web page, I need to match the daily observations with the weather information of the nearest weather station. I'm using **rdwd** (for data of German weather service) and already managed to combine each observation location with the nearest weather station. So I now have a data frame (my_df_example) like this with 100 rows:

```
     ID      Date         lat     long      Station_id                   Stationname
   1317186439 2019-05-03 47.77411 9.540569        4094     Weingarten, Kr. Ravensburg
   -2117439060 2019-05-19 48.87217 9.396229       10510             Winterbach/Remstal
   -630183789 2019-04-30 48.86810 9.285427        4928      Stuttgart (Schnarrenberg)
   -390672435 2019-05-10 50.71187 8.706279        1639             Giessen/Wettenberg
   262182713 2019-05-01 50.82548 8.892961        3164 Coelbe, Kr. Marburg-Biedenkopf
   -373270631 2019-05-24 51.61666 7.950153        5480                           Werl
```

with dput(my_df_example):

```
   structure(list(ID = c(1317186439L, -2117439060L, -630183789L, -390672435L, 262182713L, -373270631L,...
   Datum = structure(c(1556841600, 1558224000, 1556582400, 1557446400, 1556668800, 1558656000, 1558224000, 1557532800,..., class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
   lat = c(47.7741093721703, 48.8721672952686, 48.8681024146134, 50.7118683229165, 50.8254843786222, 51.6166575725419, 48.7357007677785,...
   long = c(9.54056899481679, 9.3962287902832, 9.28542673587799, 8.70627880096436, 8.89296054840088, 7.95015335083008, 11.3105964660645,... 
   Stations_id = c(4094L, 10510L, 4928L, 1639L, 3164L, 5480L, 3484L,... 
   Stationsname = c("Weingarten, Kr. Ravensburg", "Winterbach/Remstal", "Stuttgart (Schnarrenberg)", "Giessen/Wettenberg", "Coelbe, Kr. Marburg-Biedenkopf", "Werl",... 
   row.names = c("58501", "89910", "69539", "24379", "45331", "77191", "50028", 
   class = "data.frame")
```

What I need to do now is get the weather information for each station on that specific date. I'm trying to use the rdwd package in R to do so.
I tried two options so far, that both didn't work out.

Option 1:

```
    urls <- selectDWD(name=my_df_final$Stationsname, res="daily", var="kl", per="historical", outvec=TRUE)
    kl <- dataDWD(urls[1:100])
```

That gives me a list of 100 lists. Each list of the 100 includes the weather data for every recorded day of a certain station. So I would need to filter the data from those lists so that the date matches the dates in my_df_example. I don't know how to extract info from a list inside a list though.

Option 2:

```
   stat <- my_df_example$Stationname
   link <- selectDWD(c(stat), res="daily", var="kl", per="hist") 
  file <- dataDWD(link, read=FALSE)
  clim <- readDWD(file, varnames=TRUE)
```

The problem here is, that dataDWD doesn't work for lists. And since "link" includes multiple Station names it is not just a vector.

I don't really know if one of these options is the right way at all or if an alternative would make more sense.

Thank you for any advice you can give.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `my_df_example` by using `dput(my_df_example)`? Also, which package are you using that contains the `dataDWD` function?

Comment: I just added the dput(), but just took the first few entries of the output, so it wouldn't get to messy. I use the rdwd package for the dataDWD function!

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem:

> What I need to do now is get the weather information for each station on that specific date.

Then, once you have your list of lists (`kl`) then you can subset from this "meta"-list the information that you are looking for this way:

```
query <- lapply(kl, function(x) {
  x[which((as.Date(x$MESS_DATUM) %in% as.Date(my_final_df$Date)) &
           (x$STATIONS_ID %in% my_final_df$Station_id)), ]
})
```

`x` represents the object `kl` passed to the function definition. The `%in%` operator, as its letters indicate, will look for the elements *in* common between `$MESS_DATUM` and `$Date` variables and (&) also for the matches between `STATIONS_ID` and `Station_id` . `which()` ensures that no logical surprises occur while subsetting the data and `as.Date()` returns a common date format for both data frames.

After performing the extraction, you have to collapse the information into a single data frame. Since all the columns in all the lists inside the meta-list are the same, you can use `do.call()` + `rbind()` directly. Like:

> `query <- do.call(rbind,query)`

To avoid messy rownames, call:

> `rownames(query) <- NULL`

Then, to see the station names in the query data set, merge the query with my_final_df:

```
colnames(query)[1] <- "Station_id" # the key needs to have the samen name in both data frames
query <- merge(query,my_final_df, by = "Station_id", all = TRUE)
```

The final result looks like this:

```
   Station_id MESS_DATUM QN_3   FX  FM QN_4 RSK RSKF    SDK SHK_TAG  NM  VPM     PM  TMK   UPM  TXK TNK  TGK eor          ID       Date
2        1639 2019-05-01   10  7.1 2.0    3 0.0    0 11.383      NA 0.3  9.0 991.15 12.6 65.67 20.6 3.3 -0.4 eor  -390672435 2019-05-10
7        3164 2019-04-30   NA   NA  NA    3 0.0    0     NA       0  NA  8.9     NA 12.3 64.92 18.7 5.4  3.4 eor   262182713 2019-05-01
16       4094 2019-05-10   10 10.3 3.4    3 5.7    4  5.933      NA  NA 10.4     NA 11.9 76.04 16.8 8.5  6.8 eor  1317186439 2019-05-03
21       4928 2019-05-03   10 10.0 3.2    3 0.4    6  3.183      NA 7.5  9.0 973.66 10.4 72.38 14.2 7.8  7.3 eor  -630183789 2019-04-30
29       5480 2019-05-19   10 11.0 1.8    3 1.0    6  5.000      NA 7.2 13.0 995.10 14.0 82.38 21.8 6.8  5.2 eor  -373270631 2019-05-24
36      10510 2019-05-24   10  5.9 1.4   NA  NA   NA     NA      NA  NA   NA     NA   NA    NA   NA  NA   NA eor -2117439060 2019-05-19
        lat     long                    Stationname
2  50.71187 8.706279             Giessen/Wettenberg
7  50.82548 8.892961 Coelbe, Kr. Marburg-Biedenkopf
16 47.77411 9.540569     Weingarten, Kr. Ravensburg
21 48.86810 9.285427      Stuttgart (Schnarrenberg)
29 51.61666 7.950153                           Werl
36 48.87217 9.396229             Winterbach/Remstal
```

This data set matches the dates and station's ids and names you first provided in the `my_df_example`.

Provided more time, maybe someone will tell us how to solve this with `tidyverse` notation, because I suspect it is even more straightforward to do the subsetting-extraction algorithm with this package.

Comment: hey, thanks so much. That is already super helpful. Do you know if there is a way to filter for two conditions with the lapply command? Because right now it gives me the weather metaData for all the dates mentioned in my_df_example. Is it possible to filter for Stations_id and Date at the same time, so I'll end up with the precise weather information for the specific day of the observation?

Comment: Hey, your welcome. Sure, I forgot to include the second condition in the subsetting argument to match also the station_id. I will modify the original post to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

full = rbindlist(kl) # Convert list to one huge DF
setDT(my_df_final) # Convert your df to DT

new_df <- merge(my_df_final, full, by.x = c("ID", "Datum"), by.y = c("STATIONS_ID", "MESS_DATUM"), all.x = T) # Merge full and your df

new_df
      ID      Datum      lat     long Stations_id                   Stationsname QN_3   FX  FM QN_4 RSK RSKF   SDK
1:  1639 2019-05-10 50.71187 8.706279        1639             Giessen/Wettenberg   10  9.1 3.3    3 9.3    6 4.000
2:  3164 2019-05-01 50.82548 8.892961        3164 Coelbe, Kr. Marburg-Biedenkopf   NA   NA  NA    3 0.0    0    NA
3:  4094 2019-05-03 47.77411 9.540569        4094     Weingarten, Kr. Ravensburg   10  6.4 2.2    3 5.2    4 0.000
4:  4928 2019-04-30 48.86810 9.285427        4928      Stuttgart (Schnarrenberg)   10  7.9 2.7    3 0.0    6 3.583
5: 10510 2019-05-19 48.87217 9.396229       10510             Winterbach/Remstal   10 11.3 1.8   NA  NA   NA    NA
   SHK_TAG  NM  VPM     PM  TMK   UPM  TXK TNK TGK eor
1:      NA 6.6 10.2 985.16 11.1 78.21 15.9 7.7 5.9 eor
2:      NA  NA  9.7     NA 12.3 71.00 20.0 3.2 1.4 eor
3:      NA  NA 10.0     NA  8.7 88.92 11.6 5.3 3.0 eor
4:       0 4.9  9.3 981.55 10.5 75.58 15.3 7.3 3.7 eor
5:      NA  NA   NA     NA   NA    NA   NA  NA  NA eor
```

(should also work in base R, but is certainly faster this way)